# How to run MSyS2 Mingw64 bash in VsCode terminal along with cmd prompt?

Tags: visual-studio-code, mingw-w64, msys2

I have my settings set as :

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows":"C:\\msys64\\usr\\bin\\bash.exe",
    "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": ["-i"],
    "terminal.integrated.env.windows": {
        "PATH": "/mingw64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/c/Windows/System32:/c/Windows:/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/"
    },
```

this works fine, but to change my terminal to Cmd Prompt I have to manually change my setting to :
    `"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe"`

I tried using the shell launcher extension to make switching between terminals easier, but that doesn't work for mingw bash. I use the extension for running Octave gui which works fine. I guess it is because no Path is specified for the shell when launching through this extension. Is there anything else I can do?

```
"shellLauncher.shells.windows": [
        {
            "shell": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe",
            "label": "Cmd Prompt"
        },
        {
            "shell": "C:\\Windows\\<sysnative>\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe",
            "label": "PowerShell"
        },
        {
            "shell": "C:\\msys64\\usr\\bin\\bash.exe",
            "label": "mingw bash"
        },
        {
            "shell": "C:\\Octave\\Octave-5.2.0\\mingw64\\bin\\octave-gui.exe",
            "label": "Octave gui"
        }
    ],
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{
            "shell": "C:\\msys64\\usr\\bin\\bash.exe",
            "label": "mingw bash",
            "env" : {"PATH": "/mingw64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/c/Windows/System32:/c/Windows:/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/"
            }
        }
```